# Remove On-screen volume display from ipad

Tags: ipad, sound-volume

I want to stop the onscreen volume display from popping up when I change the volume.

The icon is too big and blocks the center of my screen, and stays there for a second or two. I know I'm changing the volume - I'm pressing the buttons!

Is there a way to disable this icon?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to disable the animation when using the physical buttons. If the icon shows up for far longer than the buttons are pressed, I would suspect your volume button might be stuck or there's hardware / sensor damage inside.

For a workaround, I have an iPad with a similar problem, and I use AssistiveTouch

- Device > Volume Control (tap a few times) to dismiss the popup.

Comment: Thank you. I've been using this for a while now. I wish there was a neater way... though once I got used to it it's not bad.

Comment: And I switched to a new case and the volume stopped changing at random intervals.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no there's not. The indicator isn't there to tell you you changed the volume as much as its there to tell you what you've changed the volume to.

Answer (score -1):

If you jailbreak, there's some tweaks that remove this or move it to the status bar.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.